# Samples and tips on using GroovyResourceLoader

Tags: groovy

I am attempting to install my own GroovyResourceLoader and was wondering if there was an authorative guide somewhere describing all hte moving bits.

Ive noticed when groovy attempts to compile a script, it does attempt to find types by sending paths to the GRL. However it does some strange things sometimes it uses '$' as a separator and other times it uses plain old '.'.

Heres a snapshot of some logging of an attempt to load something. Ignoring the auto import stuff, notice how it using '$' as the package separator and then by replacing each '$' it one at a time with a '.'.

```
-->a$b$groovy$X$Something
-->a.b$groovy$X$Something
-->a.b.groovy$X$Something
```

Im using Groovy 1.8.0.

Comment: Do you have some example code which shows this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The "$" you see come from Groovy trying to match inner classes. I strongly assume you have somewhere an "a.b.groovy.X.Something" which will lead groovy to try to discover all kinds of inner class combinations for this one. You could for example have a "a$b$groovy$X$Something.groovy" file.